# How the twig caching exactly work?

Tags: php, twig

I have recently start work with twig in my project, 
I have check that twig have create cache folder, and check that twig basically create some php classes for cache,

I want to understand exactly how this mechanism is work, how it beneficial to reduce the page loading time, any one can help me ?

Comment: You can have a look at twig documentation `http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/internals.html` for better understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twig evaluation process looks like:

1. Your templates are parsed, [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (AST) is built from then and then AST is transformed into php code
2. Php code from the step #1 is evaluated

With Twig templates caching you eliminate step #1, since the transformation results are written to a cache files.

So it is **highly recommended** to use it on production. Just make sure you clear the template directory cache on deploy or specify another directory as a target. It could be a good idea to include the application version number in the path.

Comment: What's AST ... ?

Comment: @MartinAJ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree